# how can i improve upon Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<PAXType, BigDecimal>>> using guava

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I have the following data structure for the entity relationships:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<PAXType, BigDecimal>>>
```

Entity Relationships:

- 1 `Package`(**P**) has Many `Variants`(**V**)
- 1 `Variants`(**V**) has Many `Price` data-points
- `Price` is based on the `PAXType` (which is an **enum**: Adult, Child, Infant)

I modelled this using:

```
Map<Package, Map<Variant, Map<PAXType, BigDecimal>>>
```

for the purpose of quick price lookup based on

- package
- package variant

The way I'm using this right now is:
As I read data from the db, I create/update the above map. After I get all the info, for each variant, I need to transform the price map, from `Map<PAXType, BigDecimal>` to `Map<OccupancyType, BigDecimal>`, where OccupancyType is another enum. This is the final price format which I need to output for serialization etc.

Is there any data structure in guava which would be a good fit for the ugly map construct I have and support the operations I suggested above ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Tomasz's answer suggesting encapsulating `Map<PAXType, BigDecimal>` in class `PriceByType` (note that if `PAXType` is an enum, you should use EnumMap) I think you should consider using [Guava's Table](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) as substitution for `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, PriceByType>>`. Table use case:

> Typically, when you are trying to index on more than one key at a
>   time, you will wind up with something like `Map<FirstName,
>   Map<LastName, Person>>`, which is ugly and awkward to use. Guava
>   provides a new collection type, Table, which supports this use case
>   for any "row" type and "column" type.

Your indexes are package and package variant, both Integers, so table should end up with `Table<Integer, Integer, PriceByType>`.

Comment: +1 for both `EnumMap` and `Table` suggestions (so, after all, Guava *does* provide a helper for what OP needs).

Answer (score 3):

Guava has nothing to do here, you need to create few objects with meaningful names. First encapsulate `Map<PAXType, BigDecimal>` into e.g. `PriceByType` class holding this map:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, PriceByType>>
```

Now proceed with `Map<Integer, PriceByType>` in the same way:

```
Map<Integer, PriceByVariant>
```

The final map can be called `priceByPackage`. Now create few helper methods to query these classes effectively:

```
public class PriceByType {

    private final Map<PAXType, BigDecimal> byType = //...

    public BigDecimal find(PAXType type) {
        return byType.get(type);
    }

}
```

and:

```
public class PriceByVariant {

    private final Map<Integer, PriceByType> byVariant = //...

    public BigDecimal find(int variant, PAXType type) {
        //handle unknown values here
        return byVariant.get(variant).find(type);
    }

}
```